# Add 2 histograms fit line and change colour

Tags: matlab, colors, histogram, normal-distribution

I have the following code:

```
% Histograms
histfit(S,40,'normal')
hold on;
hist(R,40,'normal')
g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
set(gca,'Fontsize',18,'Fontname','euclid')
xlabel('R & S')
hold off;
```

I can only add one for the fist histogram the fit line.
I want to change the colour of fit line of the first histogram and to add and change the fit line colour of the second histogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are missing a call to histfit for your second histogram, so the line does not appear at all. Here is a sample code which works fine. Notice how I use findobj to fetch the actual lines and change their colors:

```
rng default; % For reproducibility

%// Generate dummy data
S = normrnd(10,1,100,1);

R = 3*normrnd(10,1,100,1);

% Histograms
histfit(S,40,'normal')
hold on;
histfit(R,40,'normal')



%// Get the lines here
hLines = findobj('Type','Line')

set(hLines(1),'Color','k')
set(hLines(2),'Color','b')

g=findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
set(g(1),'FaceColor',[0 .5 .5],'EdgeColor','w')
set(g(2),'FaceColor',[0 1 1],'EdgeColor','w')
set(gca,'Fontsize',18,'Fontname','euclid')
xlabel('R & S')
hold off;
```

giving this:

[image]

Comment: That's just what i needed man! You ROCK! Thanks a lot mate! Regards ;)